# (Client - Server) Java control when Server's serversocket accepts client(s) is not working

Tags: java, sockets, client-server, serversocket

I am currently learning about Sockets and my homework is to create a chat room where multiple clients can talk freely. The hint given by the teacher was that the chat room server only accepts the client when the client attempts to send a message. This homework is supposed to be done without using threads.

Following the hint given, I tried to create unbound ServerSocket and Socket in both the client and the server code. The key idea is that when the client attemps to send a message to the server, the client code would connect the unbound Socket, which will then trigger the server to connect the unbound ServerSocket and to accept the client.

However, when I run the code, both the server and client code are running, and they claim that all the connections are made, but I could not transmit messages between the client and the server at all.

I have tried finding answers online, but I could not find any. I would like to ask if my way of deciding when the server accepts the client is correct.

my ChatRoom Server:

```
public class ChatRoom {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        int portNum = 4321;

        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket();

        int count = 1;

        while (true) {

            // redeclare everything each round
            Socket socket = null;
            PrintWriter out = null;
            BufferedReader in = null;
            BufferedReader stdIn = null;
            String inputLine = null;

            // accept each time round
            serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(portNum));
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("newly accepted!");

            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            if (!((inputLine = in.readLine()).equals("Bye"))) {
                System.out.println("Client says: " + inputLine);
                out.println(stdIn.readLine());
                out.flush();

                System.out.println("Message Count: " + count);
                count++;
            }
            else {
                out.println(inputLine);
                serverSocket.close();
                socket.close();
                out.close();
                in.close();
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

my ChatRoomClient:

```
public class ChatRoomClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String hostName = "localhost";
        int portNumber = 4321;

        Socket echoSocket = new Socket();   // creates an unbound socket

        PrintWriter out = null;
        BufferedReader in = null;
        BufferedReader stdIn = null;

        String userInput;
        do {
            out = null;
            in = null;
            stdIn = null;

            // each time round the unbound socket attempts to connect to send a message
            echoSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(hostName, portNumber));
            System.out.println("successfully connected");
            out = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(echoSocket.getInputStream()));
            stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            userInput = stdIn.readLine();
            out.flush();
            System.out.println("Server says: " + in.readLine());
        }
        while (!userInput.equals("Bye"));

        // close everything
        echoSocket.close();
        in.close();
        stdIn.close();
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: THere's a number of things that are wrong / don't make a lot of sense in your code. Perhaps the [Oracle tutorial that shows exactly how to do this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html) would be a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks! It is a nice tutorial, I'll look through. However, is it possible to do it without using threads?

Comment: @Imma threads are by far the most convenient way to do it. It is possible to do *without* using threads. If you have hundreds of connections at a time, you'll run into performance issues with threads and have to do it the other way, but if you don't have many connections, just use threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The hint given by the teacher was that the chat room server only accepts the client when the client attempts to send a message. This homework is supposed to be done without using threads.

The hint given by the teacher doesn't make sense. The client has to connect, then the server accepts. The client can't send a message without connecting first. Maybe the teacher really means that the client shouldn't connect until he has something to send?

> Following the hint given, I tried to create unbound ServerSocket and Socket in both the client and the server code. The key idea is that when the client attemps to send a message to the server, the client code would connect the unbound Socket, which will then trigger the server to connect the unbound ServerSocket and to accept the client.

But that won't happen. It's impossible. If you try to connect to a port that isn't listening, you will get a `ConnectException.` The only way to put the port into listening state is to bind the `ServerSocket.` There is no magical back-door by which the server can possibly know that the client wants to connect so it should now do the bind.

> This homework is supposed to be done without using threads.

Impossible to 'create a chat room where multiple clients can talk freely' that way, unless you are expected to use non-blocking I/O, or abuse the `available()` facility, or use a connection per message, but then I don't see how you can communicate one client's messages to the other clients, unless you're allowed to batch them up.

There are too many imponderable aspects of this assignment as you have described it. The question as posed doesn't actully make sense, and your proposed solution certainly doesn't. You should just go ahead and write your program the normal way, with a connect, an accept, and some I/O. Get it working while your teacher comes up with a clarification.

Comment: thank you! I guess I had some misunderstanding of the question haha

Answer (score 0):

Ah... With out using thread for the server you will not be able to serve multiple clients.  Anyway, your current codes have issues and your logic are not correct.

- Your stdIn should be declare and instantiated outside of the loop, you don't need to keep on creating the stdIn object for each loop.
- Your "in" socket accept() and echoSocket.connect() should also be outside of the loop, this is why you are not getting any answer from the server because you are not listening on the same line.  It's like your phone, keep on FLASH to dial the new number each time.  all point to the same server, but it is different connection.

So, the idea is to establish a connection between server and client (single connection) that can communicate both way (via input and output stream).  Then you can loop and talk start with the client, then server receive, then server talk, then client receive then client talk.... until client say Bye...

for more: http://ta.cnci.org/basicirc

Answer (score 0):

thought I would like to update, I managed to solve my problem without using threads. Just sockets haha. Thought it would be good to post my answer for reference..

my ChatRoom Server:

```
public class ChatRoomServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4321);

        while(true) {
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader
                         (new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

            String inputLine = in.readLine();

            System.out.println("Client says: " + inputLine);

            in.close();
            clientSocket.close();

        }       

    }   
}
```

my ChatRoom Client:

```
public class ChatRoomClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String hostName = "localhost";
        int portNum = 4321;

        BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader
                                   (new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        while (true) {

            String userInput;

            userInput = stdIn.readLine();

            Socket echoSocket = new Socket(hostName, portNum);

            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter
                                      (echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);

            out.println(userInput);
            out.flush();

            out.close();
            echoSocket.close();

            if (userInput.equals("Bye")) {
                stdIn.close();
                break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This is a chat system? Where 'multiple clients can talk freely'? Not.

Comment: Yupp, it's a chat system that runs on the console. I don't think it's an actual chat system, because I was told to run the client file multiple times to simulate multiple clients connecting to the server